# Testing on mobile sized screen in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I've built an mvc app that i've loaded up to azure and on a desktop it looks fine. But the layout is a bit all over the place on a mobile device. Rather than publishing my changes to azure every time I make a design change is there a way I can see how it would look in a browser eg. chrome on a mobile device? One way i'm doing it is just resizing my browser on the laptop to the size of a mobile device and that kind of works but just wondering if there was a better way.

Thanks,

Jerome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **F12** option which have `toggle device toolbar` option in chrome. That would help you see the responsive respective design of your app in all the popular mobile devices chrome gives as an options to test on. plus you can use custom sizing to adjust width and height of the screen to manually check the responsivity.